# On typing ls the folder should appear in green colour

Tags: linux

When I type "ls" in the linux terminal the folder names should appear in green color and file name in black color. How do I do this?

Comment: I wonder why people actually are asking such questions, when running `man ls` should give you the answer quicker than waiting here until someone will give you the copy-paste solution. Is this the mindset?

Answer (score 1):

These colors are defined in **/etc/DIR_COLORS**

For instance, I have the following line:

```
DIR 01;34       # directory
```

Which means:

- 01 -> bold text
- 34 -> blue

**Attribute codes:**
00=none 01=bold 04=underscore 05=blink 07=reverse 08=concealed

**Text color codes:**
30=black 31=red 32=green 33=yellow 34=blue 35=magenta 36=cyan 37=white

**Background color codes:**
40=black 41=red 42=green 43=yellow 44=blue 45=magenta 46=cyan 47=white

So basically:

```
FILE 30;47         # normal file, white bg, black fg
DIR 01;32       # directory, bold, green fg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `ls --color`, you can also use the `LS_COLORS` environment variable to configure the colors you want. For example:

```
LS_COLORS="fi=32:di=37" ls --color
```

should give you files in green and directories in grey (closest thing to black that's available). See [this page](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors) on configuring LS_COLORS.

Answer (score 1):

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

then put the following lines

```
LS_COLORS='no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=01;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=0
export LS_COLORS
```

save the changes

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

and the changes should  apply every-time you login to the linux box

**PS:** you can adjust the color accordingly to your preference